# Interfaces, Classes and Code Smell

Tags: java, class, interface

Suppose I have the following `interfaces`:

```
public interface GameObject {
    void viewDetails();
}

public interface Weapon extends GameObject {
    void attack();
}

//A weapon is not the only item reloadable. A container could be refilled. 
public interface Reloadable extends GameObject {

    void replenish (final int amount);
}
```

and Implementation:

```
public final class ReloadableWeapon implements  Reloadable, Weapon {


    private String weaponName;
    private int numberofbullets;

    public ReloadableWeapon(String name, int bullets){

        this.weaponName = name;
        this.numberofbullets = bullets;
    }


    @Override
    public void replenish(final int amount) {
        this.numberofbullets = amount; 
    }

    @Override
    public void attack() {
        System.out.println(this.weaponName + " fired");
        this.numberofbullets--;
        System.out.println("Shots Left: " + this.numberofbullets);
    }


    @Override
    public void viewDetails() {
        System.out.println(this.weaponName);

    }
}
```

In Effective Java, one of the chapters suggests that I should declare my class by the `interface`. I understand the advantages, but what if I have more than one `interface`?

In my main method I declare it like so:

```
ReloadableWeapon chargeGun = new ReloadableWeapon("ChargeGun",10);
```

and use it like this:

```
public static void reloadGameWeapon(Reloadable reload){
        reload.replenish(10);
}

public static void attackGameWeapon(Weapon toAttackwith){
        toAttackwith.attack();
}
```

If I declare it by `interface`, I'll obviously only get the methods that specific interface provides. I could create another `interface` called ReloadedableWeapon but what methods would be placed there? Is how I **declared** and **used** my ReloadableWeapon bad practice or code smell?

Comment: "In Effective Java, one of the chapters suggests that I should declar [sic] my class by the interface."  To declare a class by the interface makes no sense.  You should have quoted the exact paragraph from the book.  We have no idea whether your understanding of the book is correct.

Comment: Effective Java suggests that you use the interface type when the interface represents or captures the purpose of the class. The interfaces that you are defining don't fit into this category. These interfaces are mix-ins, ie. interfaces that indicate supplemental behavior for a class (like Comparable).

Comment: These interfaces should not inherit from each other.

Comment: @LewBloch - Why not? how would you do it?

Comment: Sometimes you need multiple behaviors (methods) in an interface, but mostly it's better to have one abstract method per interface manifesting its primary semantics. The class provides the mixin. `public class ChargeGun implements Replenishable, Weapon, GameItem {`. "Programming to the interface" means that you declare a variable of each different interface according to the need of the moment. Mostly you just call the methods, `chargeGun.replenish();` rather than hurting the model by wrapping 1-line method calls. No variable needed.

Comment: @LewBloch - Could you provide a example using my code? I'm a little confused my what you mean.

Comment: @LewBloch - Are you saying just have a replenish method without the interface?

Comment: No, see my other comments. I'm talking about multiple interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a interface that extends both `Weapon` and `Reloadable`.

```
public interface WeaponReloadable extends Weapon,Reloadable {
   ...
}
```

And having this implementation :

```
public final class MyWeaponReloadable implements  WeaponReloadable  {
   ...
}
```

In this way you could create an instance of `MyReloadableWeapon` declared with the `ReloadableWeapon` interface and pass it in methods with `Reloadable` or `Weapon` parameters :

```
WeaponReloadable weaponReloadable = new MyWeaponReloadable();
reloadGameWeapon(weaponReloadable);
attackGameWeapon(weaponReloadable);
```

Comment: I thought about this, but as I said, what would go in the new ReloadableWeapon interface? Weapon and Reloadable cover what I need.

Comment: @Nexusfactor The body of that interface can be empty. Its only purpose is to provide an "intersection type".

Comment: Isn't that bad practice, creating an empty interface?

Comment: Not really. Here it is a very valid workaround for not having "first-class" type intersection. And then there are "truly empty" marker interfaces like `java.io.Serializable` or `java.util.RandomAccess`. Sometimes you need these things.

Comment: Creating an empty interface to "intersect" two interfaces is not a good or a bad practice in itself. This is a particular practice that suits to your particular requirement  : programming by interface**s** with an object that has to conform to two distinct interfaces that have no relation between.

Comment: They shouldn't because a `Replenishable` doesn't have to be a `Weapon` and because the motivation for inheritance here wasn't the domain model but the desire to declare unnecessary variables to declare unnecessary one-line cover methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could use generics to get a type intersection:

```
 public static <W extends Weapon & Reloadable> doSomething(W weapon){
     weapon.replenish(10);
     weapon.attack();
 }
```

Usually, it is easier to just create an "intersection interface"

```
interface ReloadableWeapon extends Weapon, Reloadable {}
```

but the generics approach works even with classes whose type hierarchy you cannot modify to include that new interface (i.e. third-party code).