# Why shouldn't these interfaces inherit from each other?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43820751/interfaces-classes-and-code-smell?noredirect=1#comment74686065_43820751) about interfaces and advice I read about in Effective Java. I got the answer I wanted, and all was good, until this afternoon when I signed into SO, and a comment was left saying

> These interfaces should not inherit from each other.

I asked why, but still haven't received an answer. Can someone explain why you wouldn't allow these interfaces to inherit? How would you fix it, and still keep the same functionality provided in the answer?

```
public interface GameObject {
    void viewDetails();
}

public interface Weapon extends GameObject {
    void attack();
}

//A weapon is not the only item reloadable. A container could be refilled. 
public interface Reloadable extends GameObject {
    void replenish (final int amount);
}
```

The only reason I see for these interfaces not to inherit, is the simplicity of the `GameObject` interface. It isn't providing any functionality that `toString` can't accomplish. However, it's only the beginning stages of my game, and `GameObject` will of course expand.

Comment: Inheritance implies an "is-a" relationship. So, a weapon is a game object. If that's correct according to your model, then that's fine. But if a weapon *has a* game object, then it should have a `GameObject getGameObject()` method. And if it's neither, it should neither `extend` nor have the `getGameObject()` method.

Comment: @AndyTurner - But in my game, it "is-a" GameObject. Logically, to me, items and weapons are GameObjects. I understand that if it isn't a GameOject, it shouldn't extend, but this isn't the case here.

Comment: "If that's correct according to your model, then that's fine". It was just one person's comment that they shouldn't extend, and nobody agreed enough to upvote it.

Comment: @AndyTurner - You get an upvote for that!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are worried too much about the purity of your design, to the point where you are concerned with trifling details instead of spending your time productively, that is, writing your game.

Either way does not make much of a difference.

Usually, a "GameObject" (and anything whose name ends with "Object") is a class, abstract if need be, but not an interface.  The only reason for naming an interface "SomethingObject" is if the interface also extends (or exposes by aggregation) the `Closeable` (`AutoCloseable`) interface, meaning that anyone who has a reference to it may destroy it.  So, if you take this route, the rest of your questions are answered trivially: interface Weapon may not extend GameObject, because interfaces may not extend classes, and the same goes for Reloadable, and we are done.

Now, if you insist on having a "GameObject" interface, you still have the option of either extending it for every single additional characteristic, or keeping each additional characteristic separate, without extending "GameObject". Both approaches will work.

If you promise, if you swear in the name of everything that is dear to you, that there will never be a Reloadable which is not also a GameObject, then you can go ahead and have Reloadable extend GameObject. But do you really need that?  The common practice is that we prefer using interfaces to increase the degree of branching of our inheritance tree, not to turn our inheritance tree into a graph.  (Not that it never happens, but it happens very rarely.)  So, we usually do not do that.  But if you do that, it is not the end of the world.

Also note that when we extend one interface from another, we (not always, but) usually extend the names.  So, your Weapon would be WeaponGameObject and your Reloadable would be ReloadableGameObject.

Also note that interface inheritance is rarely, if ever, necessary; you can make Reloadable a free-standing interface (that does not extend GameObject) and you can have Reloadable include a `GameObject getGameObject()` method, thus essentially linking the two entities together.  Then, your BFG9000ReloadableGameObject class may implement both Reloadable and GameObject and implement `getGameObject()` as `return this;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used a GameObject interface because if it were an abstract class, the inheritance will be very deep(Gun extends Weapon extends GameObject, etc..), and there are a number of articles explain why this is bad. I don't mind a getter, but I recently came across advice that stated a getter in an interface is code smell(as you pointed out, I worried too much about it.) According to my game logic, it makes sense.

Comment: The other commenter answered, but I'm not quite sure I understand what he is getting at.

Answer (score 0):

Do a real domain analysis. You'll find that something with `replenish` behavior, a `Replenishable`, needn't be a `Weapon` and may not care while replenishing that it's a `GameItem`. A `Vehicle` might also need replenishment. Perhaps something like

```
public interface Weapon extends GameItem {
public class ChargeGun 
  implements Replenishable, Weapon {...

public class FlyingCarpet extends GameItem
  implements Replenishable, Vehicle {...
```

It's usually better to have a class do interface mixins than interfaces inherit them. It depends on the domain and how you model it. As much as feasible you want

```
gun.replenish();
```

not

```
replenish(Replenishable Replenishable);
```

YMMV.

Comment: This is why Reloadable didn't extend weapon(not every weapon is reloadable, a sword for example). Reloadable could be applied to a container(a box, a cup). Your example seems to a little off, GameItem in the first example is an interface, in the second, it's a class, unless you mean implements. Now, replenish requires an amount. If the player were to level up and acquire bigger cartridges, so instead of 5 charges/bullets, they can now reload 10 bullets/charges, how would replenish know the amount, if it isn't a parameter?

Comment: Simply calling replenish by itself without parameter isn't enough. Provided they have cartridges in there inventory, they can then pass it as a parameter to the replenish method.

Comment: Presumably some form of a `Collection<Cartridge>` would be part of the `Player` instance state, yes? So if the `Player` instance reference were injected by the `Player` via `new ChargeGun(this)`, a simple `chargeGun.replenish();` or such is all you need. It will use its own `final Player player` member's `player.getCartridges()` instead of a method parameter. I'm not saying this is the right model or even idiom. Just one approach.There are many paths.

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with Mike here: Probably not the stage you should be worried about this.

For game development modeling the 'world' using object-oriented principles is often avoided. This is due strong coupling of objects and performance reasons. Very advanced game engines don't create specific classes for entities in the world.

If you are interested in the finer details,
check this out:
http://entity-systems-wiki.t-machine.org/